# Get id_cart_rules prestashop in order

Tags: php, prestashop, cart

I need to get the id of the cart_Rule in the command, until now and tried with

```
$this->context->cart->getCartRules();
```

But I don't get a result

Comment: what is your Prestashop version? where you run this code?

Comment: The code you use work in 1.7+. Be sure you have any rule added to the cart. The code will give you an array with all used cart rules. So you need to handle it and get all id_cart_rule

Comment: @AlexanderGrosul.. Thanks your answer it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it as follows:

```
  $regla =  $this->context->cart->getCartRules();//returns an array
  $codigo = $regla[0]["code"];
```

Working with version 1.7